# Always show the "edit" link grayed out for locked questions, independently from the reason why the question was locked

Tags: feature-request, edits, locked-questions

If I look at [Got any tips or tricks for Terminal in Mac OS X?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5435/what-are-some-tips-or-tricks-for-terminal-in-mac-os-x) I don't see any "edit" link, while I see it (although it is grayed out) on [Good movies for learning English](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7476/good-movies-for-learning-english).

> [image: apple.stackexchange.com]

> [image: english.stackexchange.com]

The difference between the questions is that [Got any tips or tricks for Terminal in Mac OS X?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5435/what-are-some-tips-or-tricks-for-terminal-in-mac-os-x) has been locked for historical significance, while [Good movies for learning English](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7476/good-movies-for-learning-english) was not locked for historically significance. The latter was locked when moderators didn't have to select a reason for locking the question. (The question was locked on May 5, 2011.)
In questions locked for historical significance voting and editing is not allowed for the question, and any of its answers. In fact, for an answer for [Got any tips or tricks for Terminal in Mac OS X?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5435/what-are-some-tips-or-tricks-for-terminal-in-mac-os-x) this is what I see.

> [image: answer on apple.stackexchange.com]

The vote buttons, and the "edit" link is not visible, differently from what I see for an answer given to [Good movies for learning English](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7476/good-movies-for-learning-english).

> [image: answer on english.stackexchange.com]

The difference between the questions is not caused by the reputation I have on the respective sites. In both the sites, the reputation I have would allow me to edit Community Wiki posts.

That is a reason more to make the "edit" link visible, but grayed out: Not being able to edit an answer because the question is locked is not the normal behavior noticed on locked questions.

Showing the "edit" link, grayed out, and with a tooltip would at least say to the users editing is not allowed because the question is locked. They would wonder why some locked questions allow editing their answers, and why some locked questions don't allow it, but that is a different history. `;)`

Comment: I always wondered that one myself.